# Root ('/') route doesnt work but another route works well laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller

How do i fix this error? i already trying to redirect the root to the my home route, but It still not working, the error says This site can’t be reached

```
Auth::routes();
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::permanentRedirect('/', '/home');
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

this is my web.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::middleware('auth')` means that you only allow authenticated users to access the route. If a non authenticated user try to access the route, he get redirected to the `login` route by default. You can see or overwrite this in the `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`. So one error could be that a non authenticated user try to access the route, he got redirected to the `login` route what is not exists.

But if an authenticated user tries to access the route, then this is not the proper way to redirect them to a specific route.

In `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` is defined where you redirect the authenticated user when they access the `/` route

You should overwrite this in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvide`

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

If you could provide a more detailed error description, it would help us pinpoint the exact reason for the error!

You have to define the `/` route to be able to redirect from, and you can define more `/` route, to navigate auth users and quests

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('login');
});

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('home');
  });
}
```

Now auth users get redirect to `home` route while quest users get redirect to `login`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering but idk why I cant access the / route in all laravel project, I just check it, and the error occur in all my project, if the error says 404 not found, I know it have route problem, but the error is This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. i also already try to add the redirect outside the auth group but still, there is no error like this in internet, I mean I couldn't find like mine

Comment: What local server are you using? And you can't reach just the / route? For example you can reach the /home route without error?

Comment: yes, i can access my /login /register /home well, only the / in all my project. Im using xampp, maybe the problem is there but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    });

try out this. Maybe you have to define the route to be able to redirect from

Comment: oh my god, it works, thank you so much, (I'm trying to fix this error since yesterday :( ) for now maybe I need to find a way to make different route for logged user and guest, cus only logged user can access home, guest will auto redirect to login page

Comment: Use middleware, you can define one / route in the auth middleware, and one in the quest middleware, I will update my answer to see what I mean